# SQL Server custom not null data type with default value is returning null

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know why, when I create a custom data type in **SQL Server**, based on a not null integer, and I assign it to a default value, I can't get this value when it is not a table definition (just a single declared variable).
Here's my code:

```
BEGIN TRAN;
GO
CREATE TYPE Province FROM INT NOT NULL;
GO
CREATE DEFAULT ProvinceDefault AS 4;
GO
EXEC sp_bindefault
'ProvinceDefault',
'Province';
GO
DECLARE @Province Province;
SELECT @Province;
GO
ROLLBACK TRAN;
```

It returns `NULL`

Comment: It is just the nature of the `DEFAULT` object, it only applies to columns. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173565.aspx) states *"When bound to a column or an alias data type, a default specifies a value to be inserted into the column to which the object is bound (or into all columns, in the case of an alias data type), when no value is explicitly supplied during an insert.*". It is not possible to specify a default value for a variable. It is also worth noting that `CREATE DEFAULT` is deprecated, so you should probably avoid using it all together.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN :-

[ @objname= ] 'object_name'

Is the name of table and column or the alias data type to which the default is to be bound. object_name is nvarchar(776) with no default. **object_name cannot be defined** with the varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), xml, or **`CLR user-defined types`**.

Link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177503.aspx

Comment: It is not a **CLR** user-defined type though, so this doesn't seem relevant. `sp_bindefault` is working fine for the OP, and does exactly what it should. The problem is that applying a default to a variable is not one of the things it does, and it is not something that can be done.